# Why is my method being called twice on iPhone/iPod but not on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

In one of my view controllers, the following function is called after a button is clicked, so that I can do some initialization and pop the current view (`ResultViewController`) and display the previous view (`GameViewController`).

```
- (IBAction)PlayNextList:(id)sender {
    NSInteger index = [[[GameStore defaultStore] allLists] indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:[[GameStore defaultStore] selectedList] ];

    if(index == [[[GameStore defaultStore] allLists] count]-1)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    index++;
    [[GameStore defaultStore] setSelectedList:[[[GameStore defaultStore] allLists] objectAtIndex:index]];
    [[GameStore defaultStore] resetGame]; 

    [[GameStore defaultStore] createResult];
    NSLog(@"Press Next List");
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[[GameStore defaultStore] allLists] objectAtIndex:index] label]);
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

On iPhone/iPod, I noticed that `[[GameStore defaultStore] createResult];` is being called twice but it's only being called once on iPad.

After trying to figure out why it's being called twice, I found out that the second call happened between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` of the `GameViewController`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function and when it gets hit, look at the backtrace. That will give you feedback as to what's calling it twice/once.

Comment: Have you set a break point there and looked at the stack trace for each call?

Comment: @BP can you post your comment as an answer.  You were right on.  I copy and paste another button to create the button and it included the connection to another function that called createResult and i forgot to remove the connection.  THANK YOU!!! I spent hours trying to figured this out last night.

Comment: OK, I posted the comment as an answer and deleted the comment. I have had this happen to me a few times, it can be maddening to track down. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to check the connections inspector for the event that fires to activate PlayNextList, especially if you have different NIB files for iPhone and iPad, and make sure that event is not wired up twice to the same method.